# mod_auth_kerb principal parsing error

Tags: apache, security, kerberos

I'm using mod_auth_kerb & Apache HTTPD to authenticate website users against a Kerberos server. I'm receiving a strange error message in my Apache error log. (Please note, I've changed the principal in this post for security reasons, but the format remains the same). Turning on debug level output for Apache allowed me to obtain more informative logs:

```
[debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1932): [client x.x.x.x] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1277): [client x.x.x.x] Acquiring creds for HTTP/kerberos_server.example.com@REALM.EXAMPLE.COM
[debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1470): [client x.x.x.x] Credentials cache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_48 not found, create one
[error] [client x.x.x.x] Could not parse principal HTTP/kerberos_server.example.com@REALM.EXAMPLE.COM/server_hostname: Malformed representation of principal (-1765328250)
[debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1598): [client x.x.x.x] Failed to obtain credentials for s4u2proxy
[debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1137): [client x.x.x.x] GSS-API major_status:000d0000, minor_status:0000000d
[error] [client x.x.x.x] gss_acquire_cred() failed: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information (, Permission denied)
```

I suppose the problem is with the "/server_hostname" at the end of the principal. In my Kerberos keytab file the principal is listed as `HTTP/kerberos_server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM`. How can I change the principal that is submitted to mod_auth_kerb? Or is there another way to reconcile this parsing error?

Comment: You question is not very clear. Are you talking about the context initiator principal or the prinicipal for which the SPN (acceptor) exists in the keytab?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm talking about the context initiator principal. It's got an extra "/hostname" at the end which I can't find documentation for. In fact, according to http://cryptnet.net/mirrors/docs/krb5api.html, "The realm in a Kerberos name may not contain the slash, colon or null characters." So I'm confused why the realm portion of the context initiator principal would contain a slash at all.

Comment: I second your statement, please have a look at this: http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-user/What-is-a-Kerberos-Principal_003f.html It defines the syntax of a Kerberos principal. HAve you asked your admin about that? What KDC do you use? AD, MIT or Heimdal?

Comment: So basically, what I think is happening is that something is providing an invalid principal string to mod_auth_kerb, which in turn can't parse the principal. So my question is how can I affect what gets passed in? I'm looking into what KDC we use, but it will take some time to find out.

Comment: As an app/web server admin you have no influence. This is the KDC admin's task. He needs to query the KDC and find all invalid principal. Interestingly how did those PNs get into the KDC at all?

Comment: @Michael-O, I turned on debug output in Apache to get more information. It seems that something within mod_auth_kerb or the "gss" includes is tacking on the extra "/server_hostname". The initial credential that is provided appears to be in the correct form. Any thoughts? I hope this question is not too nieve! I'm just learning how Kerberos works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out to be a file system permission problem. The keytab was owned by root:root, and permissions were set to read/write for owner only (0600). Therefore, Apache HTTPD was not able to access the keytab file. I still don't know how mod_auth_kerb was coming up with the context initiator principal that it was. But, now that the keytab is readable by Apache everything is working properly.

Comment: You can do `setfacl -m u:apache:r-- /etc/krb5.keytab` on CentOS 7 (and earlier) to fix it.